# Using the MongoDB shell, how can I view a truncated version of the contents of a collection?

Tags: mongodb

Each document in this collection has several small string properties that I would like to view side-by-side a la `db.collection.find()`, but one property in each document is a big array (1k+ entries) that I'd rather not have fill up my shell.

Is there any way to preview shorter properties in a collection without printing the long ones (similar to how Chrome dev tools would display an object in the console)?

Comment: also try this http://robomongo.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Simply use projection:

```
db.collection.find({fieldA: "foo"},{fieldYouDontWantToSeeA:0})
```

See [MongoDB's find documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) for details.